# How to change div border automatically when more children are added to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class='faq_details'>
    <li class='faq_quest'>
        <a class='faq_row_question'>" + question</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

I read questions from XML file and show them in HTML.
Now, I want to add the answer on for each question when click
and code is:

```
$(".faq_row_question").click(function () {
    var answer = xml.find('row').eq(0).find('answer').text();
    $(this).append( answer );     
});
```

The CSS code:

```
.faq_details {
    position:relative;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: gainsboro;
    margin-right: -24px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
```

As you can see, each question is inside a border.

I want to add answer when click inside the same border of the question div.

How can I manage it? Any suggestions?

Comment: change height to min-height

Comment: Close the `<a>` tag correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using fix height for your class.
You need to use min-height like bellow:

```
.faq_details {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 30px; //Use min-height here
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  margin-right: -24px;
  padding-right: 17px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```